# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous - tensorflow 2.0 works, but not in tensorflow 2.9

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am studying reinforcement learning, the course was developed in tensorflow 2.0 and now I am tensorflow 2.9.

When I run the following code in the tf 2.0, it works fine, but in the version 2.9 I got the following message.

ERROR
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 1, 11
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Doing some research I have found that tf dropped support for treating inner lists and it should change the list for np.array, but it didn't work.

Here is the batch.append below.

## FULL CODE

### Step 1: Colab Libraries

```py
!pip install pandas-datareader
```

```py
!pip install tqdm
```

```py
!pip install -q yfinance
```

### Step 2: Libraries

```py
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as data_reader
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal #import alterado

from tqdm import tqdm_notebook, tqdm
from collections import deque
import yfinance as yf
```

### Step 3: building the AI for stock trading

```py
class AI_Trader():
  
  def __init__(self, state_size, action_space = 3, model_name = "AITrader"):
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_space = action_space
    self.memory = deque(maxlen = 2000)
    self.model_name = model_name
    
    self.gamma = 0.95
    self.epsilon = 1.0
    self.epsilon_final = 0.01
    self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
    self.model = self.model_builder()
    
  def model_builder(self):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(self.state_size,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 32, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = self.action_space, activation = "linear"))
    model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001))
    return model

  
  def trade(self, state):
    if random.random() <= self.epsilon:
      return random.randrange(self.action_space)
    
    actions = self.model.predict(state)
    return np.argmax(actions[0])
  
# Possible error is here

  def batch_train(self, batch_size):
    batch = []
    for i in range(len(self.memory) - batch_size + 1, len(self.memory)):
      batch.append(self.memory[i])

    for state, action, reward, next_state, done in batch:
      if not done:
        reward = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])
        
      target = self.model.predict(state)
      target[0][action] = reward
      
      self.model.fit(state, target, epochs=1, verbose=0)
      
    if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_final:
      self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

### Step 4: Pre-processing

##### Sigmoid

```py
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

##### Price formatting

```py
def stocks_price_format(n):
  if n < 0:
    return "- $ {0:2f}".format(abs(n))
  else:
    return "$ {0:2f}".format(abs(n))
```

##### Loading the data

```py
#dataset = data_reader.DataReader("AAPL", data_source = "yahoo")
dataset = yf.download("AAPL", start='2016-06-02')
```

```py
def dataset_loader(stock_name):
  #dataset = data_reader.DataReader(stock_name, data_source = "yahoo")
  dataset = yf.download(stock_name, start='2016-06-02')
  start_date = str(dataset.index[0]).split()[0]
  end_date = str(dataset.index[-1]).split()[0]
  close = np.array(dataset['Close'])
  return close
```

#### States

```py
def state_creator(data, timestep, window_size):
  starting_id = timestep - window_size + 1
  
  if starting_id >= 0:
    # windowed_data = data[starting_id:timestep + 1] # Atualizado 14/03/2022
    windowed_data = np.array(data[starting_id:timestep + 1]) # Atualizado 14/03/2022
  else:
    # windowed_data = - starting_id * [data[0]] + list(data[0:timestep + 1]) # Atualizado 14/03/2022
    windowed_data = np.array(- starting_id * [data[0]] + list(data[0:timestep + 1])) # Atualizado 14/03/2022
    
  state = []
  for i in range(window_size - 1):
    state.append(sigmoid(windowed_data[i + 1] - windowed_data[i]))
    
  return np.array([state]), windowed_data
```

#### Loading the data

```py
stock_name = "AAPL"
data = dataset_loader(stock_name)
```

### Etapa 5: Treinando a IA

#### Configuração dos hyper parâmetros

```py
window_size = 10
episodes = 1000
batch_size = 32
data_samples = len(data) - 1
```

#### Model

```py
trader = AI_Trader(window_size)
```

```py
trader.model.summary()
```

#### Loop training

```py
for episode in range(1, episodes + 1):
  print("Episode: {}/{}".format(episode, episodes))
  state = state_creator(data, 0, window_size + 1)
  total_profit = 0
  trader.inventory = []
  for t in tqdm(range(data_samples)):
    action = trader.trade(state)
    next_state = state_creator(data, t + 1, window_size + 1)
    reward = 0
    
    if action == 1: # Comprando uma ação
      trader.inventory.append(data[t])
      print("AI Trader bought: ", stocks_price_format(data[t]))
    elif action == 2 and len(trader.inventory) > 0: # Vendendo uma ação  
      buy_price = trader.inventory.pop(0)
      
      reward = max(data[t] - buy_price, 0)
      total_profit += data[t] - buy_price
      print("AI Trader sold: ", stocks_price_format(data[t]), " Profit: " + stocks_price_format(data[t] - buy_price))
      
    if t == data_samples - 1:
      done = True
    else:
      done = False
      
    trader.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
    
    state = next_state
    
    if done:
      print("########################")
      print("Total profit: {}".format(total_profit))
      print("########################")

    if len(trader.memory) > batch_size:
      trader.batch_train(batch_size)
     
  if episode % 10 == 0:
    trader.model.save("ai_trader_{}.h5".format(episode))
```

### Processing and the error

```
Episode: 1/1000


  2%|▏         | 32/1624 [00:00<00:00, 2444.06it/s]

AI Trader bought:  $ 24.480000
AI Trader sold:  $ 24.657499  Profit: $ 0.177500
AI Trader bought:  $ 24.735001
AI Trader sold:  $ 24.912500  Profit: $ 0.177500
AI Trader bought:  $ 24.365000
AI Trader sold:  $ 24.387501  Profit: $ 0.022501
AI Trader bought:  $ 23.350000
AI Trader sold:  $ 23.010000  Profit: - $ 0.340000
AI Trader bought:  $ 23.397499
AI Trader sold:  $ 23.600000  Profit: $ 0.202501
AI Trader bought:  $ 23.747499
AI Trader sold:  $ 23.882500  Profit: $ 0.135000
AI Trader bought:  $ 24.697500
AI Trader sold:  $ 24.695000  Profit: - $ 0.002501
AI Trader bought:  $ 24.967501






---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/var/folders/r4/qwjyzqg93bs_03_jw6c69zmc0000gn/T/ipykernel_50952/642120141.py in <module>
     34 
     35     if len(trader.memory) > batch_size:
---> 36       trader.batch_train(batch_size)
     37 
     38   if episode % 10 == 0:


/var/folders/r4/qwjyzqg93bs_03_jw6c69zmc0000gn/T/ipykernel_50952/2482695830.py in batch_train(self, batch_size)
     49     for state, action, reward, next_state, done in batch:
     50       if not done:
---> 51         reward = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])
     52 
     53       target = self.model.predict(state)


~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb


~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1849             )
   1850         msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1851         raise ValueError(msg)
   1852 
   1853 


ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1, 11
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

I am trying to run this notebook in tensorflow 2.9, but it only works in tensorflow 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that the data contains NAN values ?

Comment: This seams to not the issue. The TF doesn't support lists anymore, but I could not change from list to array.

The database is complete, there is no empty values.